# Could this work as a Generic Factory method?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics, factory-pattern

Just fooling around and I got this idea, is this a good implementation for a generic factory method pattern?

Factory Code:

```
public static class Factory
{
    public static T Create<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Calling the Factory somewhere else:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var obj = Factory.Create<Person>();
            obj.Name = "Mark";
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);

            var obj2 = Factory.Create<Animal>();
            obj2.AnimalType= "Dog";
            Console.WriteLine(obj2.AnimalType);

            dynamic obj3 = Factory.Create<ExpandoObject>();
            obj3.Age= 20;

            Console.WriteLine(obj3.Age);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

I mean is working as expected... but do you see any problem here? Cause I don't...

Any advice will be more than appreciated because I am planning to use factories to instantiate the objects and these seems good..

Thanks in advance :D

**EDIT**: I modified the name of the factory method in order to clarify the question since the previous name was GetInstance and It was confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure that I really understanding Factory since I only read the "Head-first : design pattern". However, in my experience, a factory should produce some products that have same ancestor (or implement same interface). And your factory only restrict by "new()" condition. I think it means every T is successor of `Object`, but `Object` didn't provide `Age`, `AnimalType` or `Name`. In my opinion, the factory should be more condition of the T.

Comment: Use [autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/). You're factory will return a new instance when you call GetInstance for the same type twice

Comment: @COLDTOLD just doing some random stuff, var would have worked fine too.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit isn´t that the idea of the factory? I´m not trying any singleton for the product of the factory.

Comment: I think it should be possible to return singletons for types you register as singleton but i'm no factory expert.

Comment: Agree with the answers here, though one use might be to help mocking in unit tests. If the factory were not static, you could pass a mock of it to your method and set it up to return mock objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is technically correct but IMO useless. You have no benefit from using this Factory. It's even much easier to use **new** for every new instance you need. So, this is a problem.

In fact, it's pretty much defeating the reason to have a factory. It doesn't return an abstraction and it isn't suitable to build an expensive object. Also, your code would be coupled to the Factory.

A DI Container, autofac is very good, is pretty much a factory and knows how to handle the instantiation of any type registered to it. Also, it can be used to inject any isntance you'd need as a dependency.

In conclusion, I'd say to use the *new* keyword for simple cases and a DI Container for objects with dependencies. The Factory class you wrote and its usage seem more like bad code actually, so don't use it in a real app.

Answer (score 0):

The example works fine, but I can hardly imagine a situation where you realy need this. The only usage that came to my mind is when you need to do some logging or something like that upon every object creation action. Otherwise you can just call a target type constructor.
Usualy you use factory to create different objects that implement common interface. Thus the client of factory has no knowlege about exact implementation of used interface which leads to less coupled solution. Basicaly the factory knows about concrete realisation of some interface and the consumer of the factory doesn't, that's the main idea.

Comment: Implementing logging via autofac: builder.RegisterType<MyObject>()
   .OnActivated(e => e.Context.Resolve<ILogWriter>().Log("Object created"));

Comment: @MikeSW, I agree. In general almost any IoC container has this functionality, and in most cases one should use IoC container than create custom factory method.